# Как в цикле запустить таймер n раз только после окончания счета предыдущего таймера?

Tags: java, android, таймер

У меня имеется таймер

```
    private void startCounting()
{
    final long time_exercise = Long.parseLong(set_exercise.getText().toString());
    new CountDownTimer(time_exercise * 1000, 500)
    {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            timer_exercise.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }

        public void onFinish()
        {
            timer_exercise.setText("0");
        }
    }
    .start();
}
```

Мне нужно после окончания таймера запустить его снова. Я мог бы запустить новый в `onFinish`, но количество запусков неизвестно и задаётся через `EditText`. Поэтому я хочу запустить таймер в цикле n раз подряд, но, как я понял, цикл запускает сразу все таймеры в разных потоках (?)

Как в цикле запустить таймер n раз только после окончания счета предыдущего таймера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В метод startCounting() передаете нужное количество запусков, при старте минусует от количества 1 в финише проверяете, если счетчик больше 0 вызываете метод еще раз

```
private void startCounting(int count){
final long time_exercise = Long.parseLong(set_exercise.getText().toString());
count--; //
new CountDownTimer(time_exercise * 1000, 500){

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
        timer_exercise.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
    }

    public void onFinish(){
      timer_exercise.setText("0");
      if(count > 0){
       startCounting(count)
      }
    }
}
 .start();
}
```